# Is there a way in Qt / QLocale to get the script of a language?

Tags: qt, locale, qlocale

**EDIT:** As per the comments below, this is only an issue with older Qt versions. It works as expected since at least Qt 5.12.8.

Using the `QLocale` class of Qt, I want to get the scripts which are typically used with a given language. I came up with this:

```
QSet<QLocale::Script> scriptsOfLanguage(QLocale::Language language) {
    QSet<QLocale::Script> scripts;
    for (const auto &locale : QLocale::matchingLocales(language, QLocale::AnyScript, QLocale::AnyCountry)) {
        scripts.insert(locale.script());
    }
    scripts.remove(QLocale::AnyScript);
    return scripts;
}
```

However, for some reason this code only works for languages which use at least **two different scripts**:

- `scriptsOfLanguage(QLocale::Chinese)` correctly returns `QSet(QLocale::SimplifiedHanScript, QLocale::TraditionalHanScript)`
- However, `scriptsOfLanguage(QLocale::French)` returns `QSet()` instead of the expected `QSet(QLocale::LatinScript)`
- Likewise, `scriptsOfLanguage(QLocale::Arabic)` also returns `QSet()` instead of the expected `QSet(QLocale::ArabicScript)`

So, this code doesn't work as expected for most languages. What am I missing here, and what can I do about it (except to maybe hard-code [this list of scripts and their associated languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_writing_systems#List_of_writing_systems_by_adoption) into a huge `switch` statement)?

Comment: On Windows 10 and Qt 6.5.1, I have the correct values for all 3 languages of your question. Your issue does not seem to be in the code you shared.

Comment: Confirmed. In Qt 5.12.8, it also works as expected. So this is only an issue when using older Qt versions. Sorry.